# How to use the "Helvetica Neue Bold Condensed" in the HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So the question is, how can I use "Helvetica Neue Bold Condensed" in the HTML5 Canvas.

---

I've tried:

```
context.font = "20pt 'HelveticaNeue-BoldCondensed'";
context.font = "20pt 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold'";
context.font = "20pt 'Helvetica Neue Bold Condensed'";
```

none of them work.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `font-weight` or something?

Comment: where should I put it?
it's a context variable.
Whole code will look something like this:
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.font = "20pt 'Helvetica Neue Bold Condensed'";
    context.fillText("Hello World", 100, 100);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different things that could be wrong:

1. Are you **including** the web-font (if you aren't assuming it's on your own computer)? You can double-check this by setting the `font-family` to another, plain HTML element and see it if works.
2. Do you have the proper files in the [correct format for your browser/version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360592/custom-web-font-not-working-in-ie9/12361841#12361841)?
3. You're not calling it by it's "actual" font family name. Sometimes these can be bizarre, so you may need to check with a [font viewer](http://www.dafont.com/soft.php#1) or an [online service](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).
4. [Ol' man Miedinger](http://www.linotype.com/522/maxmiedinger.html) is haunting you because you're stealing his greatest work.

**I would encourage you not to use fonts that you do not have a legal license to use as web fonts.** `:)` [Google](http://www.google.com/webfonts) and [other vendors](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface) have a lot of good, free stuff out there. Use *that*.

It apparently doesn't matter if you omit the `font-weight` or `font-style`, although you need to make sure and match the `font-weight` and `font-style`s in your `@font-face` definition(s).

However, bizarrely you can end up with some strange results:

```
context.font = '40px Griffy';
context.fillText("StackOverflow", 20, 50);
context.fill();

context.font = 'normal Rye';
context.fillText("StackOverflow", 20, 100);
context.fill();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tceh5/1/

You would think it still had enough to work with, but this gives:

[image]

Leading me to believe you need to be careful and probably be as descriptive as possible. It [*can apparently use `40pt Rye`*](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tceh5/2/), while `normal Griffy` just gets ignored for the default `10px Sans-Serif`.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>​
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Griffy';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Griffy'),
         local('Griffy-Regular'),
         url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/griffy/v1/f4FUXlL5FPqftKJ2T0mqXg.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Rye';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Rye Regular'),
         local('Rye-Regular'),
         url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/rye/v1/o1b_1mvE63vyDpMCbEPL_A.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Jolly Lodger';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Jolly Lodger'),
         local('JollyLodger'),
         url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/jollylodger/v1/RX8HnkBgaEKQSHQyP9itiXhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}​
```

**Javascript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.font = 'normal 40px Griffy';
context.fillText("StackOverflow", 20, 50);
context.fill();

context.font = 'normal 40px Rye';
context.fillText("StackOverflow", 20, 100);
context.fill();

context.font = 'normal 40px "Jolly Lodger"';
context.fillText("StackOverflow", 20, 150);
context.fill();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tceh5/

Comment: heh, was working on this at the same time. Heres a fiddle as well for yours. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/hSWJe/

Comment: Yeah, I was putting some stuff together. I put some more into the answer. I still need to look into something else, too.

Comment: You see, Jared, I'm developing for iOS and it already has Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold. So I don't want to include web-fonts.
I just need that context.font = "20pt 'HelveticaNeue-BoldCondensed'";
All I need is the correct title of it :)

Comment: Do you have the font file itself?

Comment: It turned out that the correct answer was:
    `context.font = "20pt 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold'";`
Sorry, that I took your time. 
But thanks for Your help anyways! :)

Comment: Well I can't say I don't know how to use web fonts in `canvas` at least a little bit now. If you could upvote and mark as the answer, I would appreciate it (it's the little outlined checkmark to the top, left of the answer, one per question allowed).