# How to make a font glyph able to extend outside the borders of it's containing span?

Tags: css, sass, frontend

If you open this page on both chrome and Firefox:
https://quran.najah.edu/chapter/maryam?page=307

Notice the word at the center of the screenshot
In Chrome (displaying properly):

[image]

But on Firefox part of the glyph gets hidden:

[image]

My question is how in CSS can I allow it to extend on both browsers?.

Answer (score 1):

Did you linked all of the CSS font files for the browser supports? Like Woff, woff2, eot etc.

Comment: Please use all of the font formats for the browser's support. You can use third party website to do this. After that, you have to link all of the font files.

STEPS:- 
1. Convert your TTF to the eot,woff,woff2 and otf format.
2. Download the files and upload them to the directory where you uploaded the TTF file.
3. Link the new files properly
4. See the results.

Comment: I did convert it to woff and woff2, but with same issue on firefox.

Comment: Did you follow this process? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872592/use-multiple-font-face-rules-in-css/4872624